# Search criteria using Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a procedure to return the matching criteria for the passed parameter from the table
example :-

```
parameter - The big
related match from the table - The Big Bang
                               The Big
                               The big 
                               The big bang
```

I can do the case sensitive search using collation
The output should be "The big". It has to get the closest match possible
Could anyone help me to get that?

Comment: and your code that you have tried?

Comment: Have a look at the "soundex" function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql

Comment: Is the order of the results significant, i.e. do you consider "The Big Bang" _closer_ to "The big" than "The big bang"?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
create procedure usp_search 
(
  @SearchCriteria nvarchar(500)
)  
as 
begin 

select Title
from movies
where @SearchCriteria = Title COLLATE Latin1_General_CS

end
```